# How do i alternate table colors and keep the body background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

(RUN CODE PLS)
how can i change the black blocks color into white, same color as the rest of the table

```
<body style="background-color:black;">
<div style="color: white;">
<script>
    var colors = ["#f2f2f2", "#919191"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeColor() {
        var col = document.getElementById("body");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
</script>
<style>
.bouton{
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<xmp>
<!--...-->
</xmp>
</td>
<td>
<xmp>
Defines a comment
</xmp>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<xmp>
<!DOCTYPE>
</xmp>
</td>
<td>
<xmp>
Defines the document type
</xmp>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<xmp>
<a>
</xmp>
</td>
<td>
<xmp>
Defines a hyperlink
</xmp>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<xmp>
<abbr>
</xmp>
</td>
<td>
<xmp>
Defines an abbreviation or an acronym
</xmp>
</td>
</tr>
```

*dont pay atteton to this random text it would let me post causywe9yfywe yf w87f78wey f wef7 ywe f8we f87weyf we fwef87wef87yweqfqwief q fqwefweyf wuqydfwefwd w df ywdq f87wd8 fw8df wd w wd  fw fywf w 8fwddf wdf wdd wf w  i had too much code lol aueuauydyuwgudgasjhvjagefaifagfyus87agfgyufasuigdafyuf87agfg8tf7aiehgfhauy3gfyugsagf*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these two rules:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

to

```
tr {
  background-color: white;
}
td {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: This is why i love this forum so much, tnx soooooo much bro